# Calculation of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (e^{\sec x})}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (e^{\sec 2x})}$

Tags: limits

I'm a bit rusty with limits and derivatives at the moment. I was doing L'hosp on another problem when I got stuck here.
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (e^{\large \sec x})}{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (e^{\large\sec 2x})}$$
Further L'hosp is a mess. Care to continue, my jolly fellows?

Comment: Is the motivation for your limit the calculation of this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{\sec x}}{e^{\sec 2x}}$$

Because if so, this limit can (and should) be calculated without l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: ...indeed, MUST be calculated without l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @SimonS And even without a $\lim$ because $\sec 0 = 1$, so the whole thing is $1$.

Comment: @SimonS: It was initially something more complicated than that but yes, I did reduce it down to $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-e^{\sec x}}{1 - e^{\sec 2x}}$$

Comment: @Nick In that case, the $\lim$ makes sense again.

Comment: Yes, what @GDumphart said. So calculate it out. The derivative of $\sec x$ is $\sec x \tan x$.

Comment: @Nick Please neither use displaystyle maths (`\displaystyle, \dfrac`) nor MathJax-only titles. Both are discouraged. The former because it costs much more front-page space and the latter due to technical reasons (Users unable to invoke the browser context-menu on the link)

Comment: sec(0) = 1. So the limit you want can be calculated by directly plugging 0 for x and the answer would be 1

Comment: @chandu1729: Actually, my initial limit had $e^{\sin x} -e^{\sin2x}$. So, I thought, since it evaluated to 1, all I have left is the the other guy which you now say is 1... So, I'm pretty sure I messed up by splitting the limits and evaluating.

Comment: Please post your initial problem :)

Comment: @chandu1729: Actually, I've found a way to solve that problem. The limit in my post is much more interesting to me now. I've never actually encountered a problem with derivatives explicitly stuck in it. This was, in a way, worth the ask.

Comment: @SimonS: Ah, silly me. But I do have to admit, this was a nice question that I accidently cooked up. I'm glad for asking it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = e^{\sec x}$. Then you are looking for 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (e^{\sec x})}{\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} (e^{\sec 2x})} = \lim_{x \to 0}{f'(x) \over 2 f'(2x)}$$
Note that $f'(x) = \tan x \sec x \,e^{\sec x}$, so that $f'(0) = 0$. This means the limit is of $0/0$ form, so we use L'hopital, and the limit becomes
$$= \lim_{x \to 0}{f''(x) \over 4 f''(2x)}$$
Here
 $f''(x) = \sec^3 x \, e^{\sec x} + \tan^2 x \sec x \, e^{\sec x} + (\tan x \sec x)^2\, e^{\sec x}$, and $f''(0) = 1 \neq 0$. Hence the limit is ${1 \over 4}$.

Comment: i think you are missing a factor of 1/2 somewhere...

Comment: I think what you write is true as long as $L\neq0$.

Comment: corrected, thanks

Comment: Just a note: if you look at the limit of the quotient of first derivatives, you can eliminate (or evaluate) everything except for $\tan(x)/\tan(2x)$. It simplifies the expression considerably when doing l'Hopital a second time.

Answer (score 2):

Executing the derivatives we get:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}e^{1/\cos(x)}}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}e^{1/\cos(2x)}} \right)\right)
$$
$=$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(2x)}\right)\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}e^{1/\cos(x)}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2(2x)}e^{1/\cos(2x)}} \right)\right)
$$
In the last part we have factored out a surely converging part.

Using that $e^x\approx 1+x$ , $\sin(x)\approx x$ , $\cos(x)\approx 1$ , $e^{1/\cos(ax)}\approx 1+\frac{1}{\cos(ax)}\approx2$ at $x$=0 we can rewrite this as

$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\frac{x}{1}2}{\frac{2 x}{1}2} \right)\right)=\frac{1}{4}
$$

Comment: What ensures us that degree-$1$ Taylor preserves the limit? (curious)

Comment: i would say because every constituent of the expression in nominator/denominator is finite except the two sines. 
But it is obvious that there fraction will converge.

Comment: Maple gets the answer $1/4$.

Comment: mathematica too